# Hide inactive or disabled elements in the list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I am struggling with the following issue.

On my wordpress website I have a dropdown filter lists

**1**. VEHICLE TYPE (convertible, coupe etc.)

---

**2**. MAKE (Mercedes, BMW etc.)

---

**3.** MODEL (CLK, X5 etc.)

---

so, when selecting the **VEHICLE TYPE** from the **FIRST** list,

appears the corresponding **MAKES** in the **SECOND** one for the selected item,

and in the **THIRD** list appears then the model coresponding the **MAKE** (*Mercedes-CLK*,  *BMW-X5*).

Now the thing is, that the Makes or Models that are disabled or inactive won't show on DESKTOP but on MOBILE they appear although still inactive.

1ST question: How can I hide the disabled elements from the list on MOBILE?

2ND question: Can I disable the MAKES and MODELS unless chosen VEHICLE TYPE?

Here below you can see the backend code for the list.

```
var car_dealer = {};
```

(function ($) {
    /*
     * Cleans the form URL from empty parameters on submit
     */
    $('.vehicle-search-form').submit( function() {
        $(this).find( "input[type='number']" ).filter(function(){
            return ($(this).attr( 'min' ) == $(this).attr( 'value' ) || $(this).attr( 'max' ) == $(this).attr( 'value' ));
        }).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );

```
    $(this).find( "input[type='search']" ).filter(function(){
        return ! $(this).val();
    }).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );

    $(this).find( "select" ).filter(function(){
        return ! ( $(this).val() && $(this).val() != '-1');
    }).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );


})

/*
 * Disables all models that do not fit the selected make
 */
$('#car_dealer_field_vehicle_type').on('change',function(){
    var makeName = $(this).find( 'option:selected' ).attr( 'data-type' );

    $('#car_dealer_field_make option')
    // first, disable all options
    .attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' )
    // activate the corresponding models
    .filter( '[data-type="' + $.trim( makeName ) + '"], [value="-1"]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' )
    // remove previous value
    .parent().val( -1 );
});
$('#car_dealer_field_make').on('change',function(){
    var makeName = $(this).find( 'option:selected' ).attr( 'data-make' );

    $('#car_dealer_field_model option')
    // first, disable all options
    .attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' )
    // activate the corresponding models
    .filter( '[data-make="' + $.trim( makeName ) + '"], [value="-1"]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' )
    // remove previous value
    .parent().val( -1 );
});
```

}(jQuery));

I am grateful and looking forward to hear from you soon !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here we go.

Here is the event handler - reworked a slight bit to only have one selection event handler.

Now as far as the hiding and showing, simply do that to the appropriate list of options filtered as you indicate to hide the disabled ones.
Use `prop("disabled",true)` to disable, not an attribute.

I left out how to re-enable and show when that is needed but that is a simple
`.find('option').prop('disabled",false).show();`

```js
(function($) {
  /* * Cleans the form URL from empty parameters on submit */
  $('.vehicle-search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // might want to prevent the submit?
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find("input[type='number']")
      .filter(function() {
        return ($(this).attr('min') == $(this).attr('value') ||
          $(this).attr('max') == $(this).attr('value'));
      }).prop('disabled', true);

    $(this).find("input[type='search']")
      .filter(function() {
        return !$(this).val();
      }).prop('disabled', true);

    $(this).find("select").filter(function() {
      return !($(this).val() && $(this).val() != '-1');
    }).prop('disabled', true);
  });

  // here we can create one custom event handler to do the disable
  $('#car_dealer_field_make')
    .on('change', function() {
      var makeName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('make');
      $(this).trigger("custom-set-me", [makeName, "fun"]);
    });
  $('#car_dealer_field_vehicle_type')
    .on('change', function() {
      let makeName = $(this).find('option:selected').data('type');
      $(this).trigger("custom-set-me", [makeName, "fun"]);
    })
    // add the other one to the handler
    .add("#car_dealer_field_make")
    /*
     * Disables all that do not fit the selected 
     */
    .on('custom-set-me', function(event, compareTo, param2) {) {
      let iamMe = $(this);
      let options = iamMe.find('option');
      options
        .prop('disabled', true)
        // activate the corresponding models
        .filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('type') == $.trim(compareTo);
        }).val(-1).prop('disabled', false);
      // remove previous value
      iamMe.val(-1);
      options.filter(':diabled').hide();
    });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: With some decent HTML we could test this easily by putting it in there but I will forego that exercise.